# Webform import via Webform Share

Tags: webforms, installation, importing-exporting

Question: How can I import a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) via the https://drupal.org/project/webform_share API?

What do I know/current state: The API shows a graphical UI to do it, but I'd need a way to do it via an exported function, if any (e.g. a function call like webform_share_import($formspec)).

Reason/scenario: Because I want to install some forms in the .install of a module.

Answer (score 1):

Found: there's not an exported API, but an implementation of a regular form hook for the UI, which does all the magic (webform_share.module:123).

Comment: It is disappointing to answer my own questions and find a negative one :(.

Answer (score 0):

See this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share/issues/2527596#comment-10184032).

In the comments, it shows that there is a function called `_webform_share_eval()` in the webform_share.module file.

```php
function _webform_share_eval($str) {
  eval($str);
  return empty($webform) ? FALSE : $webform;
}
```

It's very simple to use this to import a webform and save a node.

```php
// Create the node
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'webform';
$node->title = 'Contact Us';
$node->status = 1;
node_object_prepare($node);

// Import the webform
$node->language = 'und';
$node->webform = _webform_share_eval(file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/webform.txt'));
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8/9 and Webform 6, there is now a Webform Share submodule in Webform itself.

This can be used to [use webforms in decoupled situations.](https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/webform-sharing)

There is a [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMgOprfJTWA).

Basic config info for global sharing of webforms:

First, go to `/admin/structure/webform/config` and *Enable form sharing* under **Form share settings**.

Then go to `/admin/structure/webform`, click the more info triangle, select **Share**, and then choose from among the three options to embed your webform.